# Why does Openssh use only SHA1 for signing and verifying of digital signatures?

Tags: hash, signature, sha-1, ssh

I am learning SSH protocol. With my current understanding of SSH protocol, I think that message digest algorithms for using in digital signature should be derived from Key Exchange. But Openssh implementation uses only SHA1 for signing and verifying of digital signatures. SHA1 is hard coded in these two functions, ssh_dss_sign() and ssh_dss_verify().

I am wondering, does all the implementations of use SHA1 as hash algorithm for signing and verifying digital signatures.  And why don't we use SHA-256 as it's better than SHA1?

Is there any specific reason for doing so..? If yes, could someone please provide some references.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose that most of the SSH protocol is older than SHA-2, and nobody bothered to add new key exchange algorithms with SHA-2 to it.

Comment: There is a MAC algorithm spec for SHA-2 in [RFC 6668](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6668).

Comment: Actually, the list of registered [key exchange method names](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ssh-parameters/ssh-parameters.xhtml#ssh-parameters-16) contains some with SHA-256.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann : OpenSSH already supports diffie-hellman-group-exhchage-sha256. So I expected it to use SHA256 in digital signatures.

Comment: I don't know SSH well, but I'd bet that Paŭlo Ebermann's first comment is right. Notice that it also uses SHA-1 for RSA, but it uses SHA-2 for ECDSA, with a comment pointing to the [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5656) [that](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5656#section-3.1.1) [mandates](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5656#section-6.2.1) it. (See `ssh_ecdsa_sign` in `ssh-ecdsa.c` and `key_ec_nid_to_hash_alg` in `key.c`.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Because the RFC says so.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-6.6)

> Signing and verifying using this key format is done according to the
> Digital Signature Standard [[FIPS-186-2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#ref-FIPS-186-2)] using the SHA-1 hash
> [[FIPS-180-2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#ref-FIPS-180-2)].

It says the same for RSA half a page down.

Apparently the signature algorithm is a defined part of the public key method's specification, rather than being negotiated separately like the MAC algorithm is.

At a guess, SHA-1 was considered good enough at the time SSH 2 was being written almost a decade ago (the RFCs were published in 2006), and no one wants to bother changing it now.

Notice that ECDSA keys, published in [RFC 5656](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5656) in 2009, [use SHA-2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5656#section-3.1.1):

> Signing and verifying is done using the Elliptic Curve Digital
> Signature Algorithm (ECDSA).  ECDSA is specified in [[SEC1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5656#ref-SEC1)].  The
> message hashing algorithm MUST be from the SHA2 family of hash
> functions [[FIPS-180-3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5656#ref-FIPS-180-3)] and is chosen according to the curve size as
> specified in [Section 6.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5656#section-6.2.1).

You can see it in action in `ssh_ecdsa_sign()` in ssh-ecdsa.c and `key_ec_nid_to_hash_alg()` in key.c.

(I'm not an expert on SSH, so please take this answer with a grain of salt.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I wanted to know. It was really very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of openssh supports sha256/512 for digital signature. 
OpenSSH 7.2 have support for sha256/512withRSA as signature algorithm.
Please refer https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.2

Comment: We shouldn't have to follow the link to get further details. Maybe also providing a quote from the reference would be a nice addition to your answer.

Comment: But only RSA, not DSA-aka-DSS which was the Question. And which _was_ proposed, as per the draft name quoted in the release notes, but not adopted or implemented. In fact OpenSSH since 7.0 in 2015-08 by default doesn't use DSS=DSA at all, though you can re-enable it; see https://superuser.com/questions/1016989/ssh-dsa-keys-no-longer-work-for-password-less-authentication and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247612/ssh-keeps-skipping-my-pubkey-and-asking-for-a-password

Answer (score -1):

Even though the ciphers have -sha1, these are actually HMAC which are keyed hashing.  HMAC-SHA1 is fine and accepted even in FIPS, even though SHA-1 is no longer accepted in FIPS.

Comment: SSH doesn't have ciphers as such, it has encryption algorithms none of which involve any `sha1` or even `sha` and separate MAC algorithms and those which use HMAC say so explicitly. But this Q is about _signature_ aka _authentication_ algorithms and none of them ever involve HMAC. You may be confusing SSH with SSL-now-TlS where the cipher**suite**, sometimes abbreviated cipher, combines KX/auth, encryption, and MAC in a single string and trailing `_SHA _SHA256 _SHA384` (but not `_SHA1`) is used for HMAC except AEAD ciphers, and in 1.2 PRF, but NOT signature hash.