# Which hash function is used for signatures ssh-rsa and ssh-dss?

Tags: hash, rsa, signature, dsa, ssh

I'm building a fuse client for ssh/sftp. I write the required ssh and sftp functions myself. Now I read in [RFC4253](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253) that before signing the data to sign is default hashed. In [RFC4253 8. "Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-8) SHA1 is mentioned as the default for ssh-dss. What is it for ssh-rsa?

Answer (score 2):

It is using always SHA-1, unless it does not. There are two new drafts to use SHA-2 functions family:

- https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-rsa-dsa-sha2-256-03 (in 2018 published as [RFC 8332](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8332))

The usage is negotiated using the protocol extension:

- https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ssh-ext-info-05 (in 2018 published as [RFC 8308](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8308))

So basically, the other answers are correct for now and the past, but for now and close future, we don't want to use SHA-1 for cryptographic signatures and possibly deprecate SHA-1 in this area. So if you will use any decently recent version of SSH, it will use SHA-2.

Comment: FWIW these were published as RFC 8332 and 8308 in 2018-03 -- although OpenSSH had implemented them since 7.2 in 2016-08.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 yes, you are right. Thank you for reminder. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In [section 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-6) of [RFC 4253](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253) it says on [page 15](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#page-15):

> The "ssh-rsa" key format has the following specific encoding:
>
> ```
>   string    "ssh-rsa"
>   mpint     e
>   mpint     n
> ```
>
> Here the 'e' and 'n' parameters form the signature key blob.
>
> Signing and verifying using this key format is performed according
> to    the RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 scheme in [[RFC3447]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447) using the SHA-1 hash.

So the answer is "SHA-1" as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've found already:

[Why does Openssh use only SHA1 for signing and verifying of digital signatures?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15051/why-does-openssh-use-only-sha1-for-signing-and-verifying-of-digital-signatures?rq=1)

So by openssh always sha1 is used.

Stef